# How to passed array or arraylist from servlet to jsp using ajax?

Tags: json, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to pass array or list from servert code to JSP using ajax call from website. Below is my code :

**Servlet**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/plain");  
        //String name = request.getParameter("name1");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String [] lb= {"Team A","Team B","Team C","Team D","Team E"};

        JSONArray jr=new JSONArray();
        jr.put(lb);

        out.print(jr);
    }
```

Any one help me in this ?

Comment: Store your array into session like `session.setAttribute("jsonArray",jr);` and you can access it anywhere using `session.getAttribute("jsonArray");`